# Render component straight into template

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a React component, which I'm building with Webpack. The component is exported from `index.js`, which is the `entry` file in the module:

```
// packages/tnetennba/index.js

class Tnetennba extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>good morning, that's a nice tnetennba</div>
    )
  }
}

export default Tnetennba
```

My webpack configs resides in different directory than the module (I'm using mono-repository), so the module itself doesn't have any build configuration files or templates to work with `webpack-dev-server`.

```
// packages/tnetennba/package.json
{
  "name": "tnetennba",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ../config/webpack.dev.js --open",
    "build": "webpack --config ../config/webpack.build.js"
  }
}
```

However, I wan't to be able to work with the component in the dev mode, and I can achieve that using HtmlWebpackPlugin:

```
// packages/config/webpack.dev.js
module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  ...
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: '../config/index.html' // <-- this path is relative, becuase webpack will be called from packages/tnetennba directory.
    })
  ]
})
```

However, I have to put `ReactDOM.render` function call **inside** my module's `index.js`, to render component into template:

```
//...
export default Tnetennba

ReactDOM.render(<Tnetennba />, document.getElementById('root')) // <-- This shouldn't be here.
```

**Question**: Is there a way, that I can avoid calling `render` inside the module, while working in dev mode? Is is possible to call React renderer within webpack?

I would like to avoid conditional rendering using node's `process` variable as well.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [HtmlWebpackIncludeAssetsPlugin](https://github.com/jharris4/html-webpack-include-assets-plugin), it allows you to add an asset to the html file, my idea is to add a js file that will call `ReactDom.render` method inside it.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
new HtmlWebpackIncludeAssetsPlugin({
  assets: [
    { path: 'path/to/bootstrap.js', type: 'js' }
  ]
})
```